# HP ProLiant DL365 G5, USB and PS/2 Do not work during Boot

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, boot, usb, bios

Good evening all,

The situation up until the REAL point of failure;

- Dual Opteron 2300 Quad-Core (I'm not positive but I think theyre running at 2.6Ghz)
- 24Gb RAM (2Rx4 PC2-5300P-555) (lost 8Gb to a bad stick on Friday)
- RAID: HP Smart Array P400i/256MB with BBWC (RAID 0/1/1+0/5)

Failure;

I am attempting to enter setup (F2 @ Boot...) to deal with a separate HDD issue (I/O error, Invalid or non-system disk, I think I've got that one covered though).  However when attempting to enter setup, NONE of my USB or PS/2 port(s) are operational.

caveat: If booted to a LiveCD USB and PS/2 work just fine making me think physical layer is out of the equation.

Here's a breakdown of what I've done so far:

- Multiple Keyboards on all USB ports

  - Rebooted (Rebooted between keyboards too)
- Multiple Keyboards with "USB > PS/2" adapters (single PS/2 port)

  - Rebooted (Rebooted between keyboards too)
- Attempted to change BIOS to enable USB

  - (BIOS is password Protected...)

    - Shut Down
- Pulled the CMOS and let it sit for about 20-min

  - (Returned CMOS "its in the proper way I checked")

    - Booted
- Adjusted Maintenance Jumper 5 to ON "Power-On Password is Disabled"
- Adjusted Maintenance Jumper 6 to ON "System Config invalid to clear NVRAM"

  - Rebooted

So for now I'm at a loss.  If anyone's got any brilliant ideas (except Drop Tests...) I'm open to ideas...

Edit1: iLO Port was never configured to my knowledge, think of me as the dying server parts-yard for future emergent repairs...

Comment: Please leave a comment if down-voting...

Comment: I believe these things are really finicky.  Try to get hold of a pure PS/2 keyboard and don't use an adapter.  I had to deal with a couple of these some time back and I recall USB keyboards never worked for me either.

Comment: Sadly thats not likely to happen. Was in front of it a bit ago and happened to catch a brief glimpse of a power flicker to the keyboard on insertion.  Repeatable with USB or ps2.  Like it reads it and then kills it.  If that helps any...

Comment: critical bits of info - what os was it running? are you trying to recover data or getting it booting again?

Comment: The HDD?  WinServr 2k3.  Just formatting it,  it would have been previously raided (1+0) and I have no way knowing which drives are it's little brothers...  I'm not really concerned about that.  The ps2 and or USB being operational are my main goal here.  After that I'm good.

Answer (score 0):

Fourth attempt for NVRAM to clear finally worked,  make sure the maintenance switch jumper #6 is set to ON.  Power the system on, and in the middle of POST, kill power.  Swap jumper number 6 back to off and boot

BIOS is wide open after this so if your in a secured environment you'll need to reconfigure evahreythang. ..